# Typescript namespace translation to Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

For the give typescript, a class is defined within a module

```
module league{
    export class Player {
        first_name: string;
        last_name: string;

        constructor(first_name: string, last_name: string){
            this.first_name = first_name;
            this.last_name=last_name;
        }
    }
}
```

and it is translated to javascript:

```
var league;
(function (league) {
    var Player = (function () {
        function Player(first_name, last_name) {
            this.first_name = first_name;
            this.last_name = last_name;
        }
        return Player;
    })();
    league.Player = Player;
})(league || (league = {}));
```

the typescript code is easy to understand but being not so familiar with javascript, can anyone explain the logic behind the javascript it generated?

Comment: Look up "IIFE", and "module pattern".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Module

Line by line explanation of `module`:

`var league;`

So that javascript doesn't throw an error that we are using an undefined variable.

```
(function (league) {
}()
```

An immediately executing function. Required since `scope` is only created by functions in javascript.

`league || (league = {}`

So that the module can be slipt into multiple parts. If its already defined it is used, otherwise `||` we create it `league = {}`

I suppose that is what you were after. Classes are a seperate subject.

## Class

Line by line. Again an immediately executing function to create a new scope (additionally it will help with inheritance, but not relevant here) :

```
var Player = (function () {

})();
```

And the body is simply a `function` that uses `this`:

```
    function Player(first_name, last_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }
```

## More

to learn more about immediately executing functions and `this` I recommend a javascript book. e.g. JavaScript good parts.